# cytoscape. highlighting multiple best paths based on constraints

Tags: path, cytoscape.js

need help on cytoscape as I am starting up using this library but can't get answer on Cytoscape guide.
I created nodes and edges with specific weights. 
I'd like to highlight for a given source and target nodes the 2 best paths. First in green and second highlighted in red.
I dont care using Dijkstra, astar, ... as long as it does the job. Both paths could follow same paths if no other choice (example if source node has only 1 connection to its neighbor). in order to filter out edge already used for first path, I create specific data (isPrimary and IsDiverse) in edge such as :
data: { id:'1', source: 'node1', target: 'node2', weight: 0, isPrimary: 0, isDiverse: 0  }. if primary path uses this edge , it will flag isPrimary to True. But cannot be able to make it work.

Do you have concrete example that would do the job as I am stuck since weeks now. 
many thx for your supports.

A.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by *best path* you mean the shortest path.

The problem you describe is known as *k-shortest path*. [Many algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing#History) have been developed to solve this problem. But unfortunately, as far as I know, none of them is implemented in Cytoscape.js.

Your best bet is to implement Yen's algorithm by utilizing the Dijkstra's algorithm in Cytoscape.js Here is a [pseudocode](https://www.ugrad.cs.ubc.ca/~cs490/2015W2/lectures/Second_Shortest__Path_in_a_Graph3.pdf) (page 13).

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your answer. I managed to add a parameters (data) onto each edge and flag it as True when used by the best path. Then to find the second best path that should not use the first best path, I create a condition to avoid using edges having flag sets to True.